# PHP/MySQL/MariaDB - Single quotes vs no quotes on TINYINT; two servers with different behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

Using Laravel codebase, I have two servers, a DEV env, and a PRODUCTION env, which exhibit different handling of single vs. no quotes in a database query.

**MySQL version in development**

```
innobd_version: 5.5.50
protocal_version: 10
version: 5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
version_compile_machine: x86_64
version_compile_os: debian-linux-gnu
```

**MariaDB in production**

```
innodb_version: 5.5.61-MariaDB-38.13
protocol_version: 10
version: 5.5.64-MariaDB
version_comment: MariaDB Server
version_compile_machine: x86_64
version_compile_os: Linux
```

Take this Laravel database query for example:

```
$records = table::all()->where('field_name', 1)->toArray();
```

'***field_name***' is, on both servers, set as TINYINT(1) and will be either a 0 or 1.

One the production server, the above query (no single quotes) works.

However, on the development server, it doesn't (it returns zero results).

On the flip, on the development server, it works if the where criteria (1) is in single quotes:

```
$records = table::all()->where('field_name', '1')->toArray();
```

But then this single-quoted version does not work on the production environment.

It's a pain as I have to wrap the statement in a server flag if statement, so it works on both envs.

It's not just this one example; it happens in a few similar places elsewhere on different tables/fields.

I'm guessing it's because one database is MySQL and the other is MariaDB. I'm wondering if I can make them both work consistently. I want the development database (MySQL 5.5.50) to handle it without single quotes. However, I'm not sure where to start looking. I welcome any advice on what could be causing this and how I can make my development server follow consistent behavior to production.

Comment: Show us the generated SQL for each machine.

Comment: Assuming that `field_name` is a numeric type, the quotes around `1` do not matter (in MySQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try disabling strict mode in your database configuration.

**config/database.php**

```php
'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        // ...
        'strict' => false,
    ],

],
```

---

**EDIT:** On closer inspection, your `field_name` queries are not actually being sent to the database.

You are fetching the entire table as a collection, then filtering it afterwards with Laravel's collection methods. This is very inefficient and should be avoided whenever possible.

```php
$records = table::all()->where('field_name', 1)->toArray();

// SQL = SELECT * FROM `table`; 

// the ->where() is done with PHP...
```

You should be writing it like this to ask the database to only return the requested records. See the difference in the SQL?

```php
$records = table::where('field_name', 1)->get()->toArray();

// SQL = SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field_name` = 1;
```

---

**EDIT:** You could also consider casting the value in your table's model, so it is always returned from the database as an integer.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

```php
protected $casts = [
    'field_name' => 'integer'
];
```

Comment: thanks but mysql > strict is already set to false in the laravel config/database.php file on both environments. 

     SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'; 
and
    SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;

both return blank